# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).popover is not a function

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery

I'm getting this error while enabling popover any solution please...

This is my popover function what's wrong with this?

```
$('#popcart').popover();
document.getElementById('popcart').setAttribute('data-bs-content', "<h5> Hello Welcome </h5>");
```

This is button of which I'm trying to change data-bs-content.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mx-2" animation="true" data-bs-container="body"
             id="popcart" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="bottom"
             data-bs-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
  Cart(<span id="cart">0</span>)
</button>
```

Comment: Are you including the library code correctly? Please make sure the code posted is a [mcve]

Comment: Your issue is that you're trying to change data-bs-content, but your error is on popover?  Remove the popover line.  Or is the issue the popover not working and the comments/code about data-bs-content are irrelevant?

Comment: one of: you haven't included the popover.js / you haven't included it before your code / you have a 2nd jquery loaded after the popover which is overwriting the popover plugin.  Most likely the first.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same error recently, if you're sure your libraries code is correctly imported, there's a probability that you have two or more jQuery instances or $ functions. Try to add the `noConflict()` function top of your code:

```
<script>
    $.noConflict();
    jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {//Here you can add any code that is using jQuery});
    // And you can use here for other instances of $
</script>
```

Comment: If this was the problem then the error would be `$ is not a function`, not `popover is not a function`

Comment: No the error is exactly 'Uncaught TypeError: $(…).popover is not a function' and as you can see the reference here is "jQuery.function"

Comment: *"libraries are correct"* and *"two or more jquery instances"* - these clearly conflict.  Better to fix the duplicate jquery instances

Comment: @freedomn-m Yes, his priority should be fixing them, but little we do know and maybe OP has another framework using $ which he has to deal with without removing this duplicate.